# How to write a custom populate for mongoose ODM?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-plugins

Mongoose has a [populate function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to deref object by id.

```
model.find(...).populate('a_ref_field')
```

I want to create a function to deference automatically by data in the field which specify collection and id

**e.g**., foo: {col:'user',id:'54c5c5c13a0b4090451f8715'}

```
model.find(...).hyperPopulate('foo')
```

It seems mongoose allow users to create plugin. Is that possible to create a plugin to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example to do so

https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate

Thanks